# Elastic Search Case Insensitive query with prefix query

Tags: elasticsearch, case-insensitive

I am new to elastic search. I have below query

```
GET deals2/_search 
{
  "size": 200,
  "_source": ["acquireInfo"],
   "query": {
    "bool": {

      "must": [
        {

         "query_string": {
           "fields": ["acquireInfo.company_name.keyword"],
           "query": "az*"
         }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

}

Here I want Elastic should gives results like case insensitive Like string start with  below like

```
"Az" 
"AZ" 
"az"
"aZ"
"Az"
```

But I am not getting all results like this way. So Anyone can please help me on that.

Example:- I have 4 documents

```
1)Aziia Avto Ust-Kamenogorsk OOO 
2)AZ Infotech Inc 
3)AZURE Midstream Partners LP 
4)State Oil Fund of the Republic of Azerbaijan
```

Now searching on `az` , should return only first 3 docs as they start with `az`  ignoring case here and not the 4th one, which also has `az` but not at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening as you are using the keyword field to index the `company_name` in your application.

**The keyword analyzer is a “noop” analyzer which returns the entire input string as a single token** for example, company name, consist of `foo`, `Foo`, `fOo` will be stored with case only and searching for `foo`, will only match `foo` as elastic search ultimately works on tokens match(which is case sensitive).

What you need is to use a [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) or some other [custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) which solves your other use-cases as well and uses [lowercase token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html) on the field and use the [match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) query which is analyzed, and uses the same analyzer which is used to index the field, this way your search query will generate the same tokens, which is stored in the index and your search will become case-insensitive.

**Edit:** Had a discussion with the user in chat and updating the answer to suit his requirements, which are below:-

**Step 1:- Define settings and mapping for index.**

Endpoint :- http://{{hostname}}:{{port}}/{{index}}

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [],
          "filter": "lowercase"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "company_name": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Step 2: Index all the documents**

Endpoint: http://{{hostname}}:{{port}}/{{index}}/_doc/ --> 1,2,3,4 etc

```
{
    "company_name" : "State Oil Fund of the Republic of Azerbaijan"
}
```

Step3 :- Search query

Endpoint:- http://{{hostname}}:{{port}}/{{index}}/_search

```
{ "query": {
    "prefix" : { "company_name" : "az" }
  }
}
```

This would bring the below expected results:-

```
{
    "took": 870,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 3,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "prerfixsearch",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2ec9df0fc-dc04-47bb-914f-91a9f20d09efd15f2506-293f-4fb2-bdc3-925684a930b5",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "company_name": "AZ Infotech Inc"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "prerfixsearch",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "160d01183-a308-4408-8ac1-a85da950f285edefaca2-0b68-41c6-ba34-21bbef57f84f",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "company_name": "Aziia Avto Ust-Kamenogorsk OOO"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "prerfixsearch",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1da878175-7db5-4332-baa7-ac47bd39b646f81c1770-7ae1-4536-baed-0a4f6b20fa38",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "company_name": "AZURE Midstream Partners LP"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**, As earlier OP didn;t mention the exclusion of 4th doc in the search result, that's the reason I suggested creating a text field, so that individuals tokens are generated but now as requirement is only the prefix search, we don't need the individual tokens and we would want only 1 token but it should be lowercased to support the case insensitive search, that's the reason I applied the custom normalizer on `company_name` field.

Comment: Thanks Let me try above suggested  way.

Comment: Sure, let me know if you need any help

Comment: I have company name like "Aziia Avto Ust-Kamenogorsk OOO", "AZ Infotech Inc" Something this way When I tried your suggest way but it also now working.  What I want if user type "az" like this so in this case it should return both results but currently not.  If user enter "Az" like this in that case I am getting one record only.

Comment: Hope you are clear with that what kind of results I want.

Comment: @DenisBhojvani, Sorry I didn't get you.. can you explain it more

Comment: Let's Assume In My Elastic Index Data stored like below way.
Aziia Avto Ust-Kamenogorsk OOO
AZ Infotech Inc
AZURE Midstream Partners LP

Now If user searching with text Like "az" In this case elastic not giving any results.

But if User Search text like "Az" in this case it giving only one results  "Aziia Avto Ust-Kamenogorsk OOO"

But In my case Both time it should returns all 3 results. Did you get now ?